# Creating instances of a class outside the main

Tags: java

I have a class which has a main method. Now, I want to create an object of the JFrame class in that class, but as a global entity and not inside the main function, how can I do it? It gives me some compilation error when I just cut the instantiation code from inside the main and paste it outside.

```
public class Driver {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Heading");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame.setSize(1000,500);;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code. Java has syntax.

Comment: Show us the code you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a static variable and static method:

```
public class YourClass {
    private static JFrame frame = createFrame();

    private static JFrame createFrame() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        // ... more code ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // make use of frame
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

You can also use a combination of a static variable and static initializer:

```
public class YourClass {
    private static JFrame frame;

    static {
        frame = new JFrame();
        // ... more code ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // make use of frame
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Grendan yes, a class variable must be used